# Is it possible to change the Roblox website theme via a Google Chome extension?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, themes, roblox

I've recently began working on a Chrome extension to modify the Roblox webpage, however I'm pretty stuck trying to change the website theme.

I want to change the web theme from Light to Dark if it is not already, however on the API (https://accountsettings.roblox.com/docs#/), there seems to not be a request URL you can use to activate the theme change.

So far I have tried manually changing all the colors to the darker theme, but that doesn't seem intuitive.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that API page, these seems to be a method for that?

If I read this correctly, you need an authenticated PATCH request to the URL `/v1/themes/User/{userID}` with the payload

```json
{"themeType":"Dark"}
```